# Win10 remembers my Bluetooth headphone, even after their deletion

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I'll try to explain with pictures, cose it looks reeealy weird.

system - Win10 (last updates for this moment)
Bt USB Dongle - Erston Bluetooth 5.1 (REALTECH chip)
headphones - JBL TUNE700BT

1. I manually deleted all BT devices from my PC (pic. 1)
   [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yrRA.png)
2. Unplugged Bt dongle + Plugged Bt dongle
3. System installs Bt radio AND... headphones:(pic. 2)
   [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfAgl.png)

, these virtual devices prevent my headphones from connecting to this Bt.
, even after the deletion of these records from the Device Manager, I cannot see my headphones in the Lookup window and cannot add them
, though, I can successfully add my headphones to other Bt networks

If I unplug + plug my dongle again - these records will appear AGAIN(!!)

How can I DELETE these virtual records?

**upd1:**
I've tried unpairing via "the modern control panel" from the start. The same result.

Comment: Why are you not using the “modern control panel” to unpair the device?

Comment: Also network connections may remain in the registry and do no harm if you remove the devices in Devices and Printers.

Comment: @DanielB, what is "modern control panel"?

Comment: @John, I tried removing in the Devices and Printers also. Same result

Comment: I have a Logi Tech BT Mouse.   Dozens and Dozens of registry entries. Just ignore them. If you leave disconnected they may go away after a couple of reboots.

Comment: @John, nor dozens of reboots nither ignoring these records doesn't help. I still can't connect my headphones to this Bt.

Comment: That may be a compatibility problem of some sort. Otherwise I am not sure. Anything compatible connects to my Windows 10 (and 11) machines.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, and found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1698018/1237326) in [a different forum](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/22049-how-completely-remove-bluetooth-device-win-10-a-2.html?s=fe7a99da39787347e49ffc1de2851cfb). This approach solved the issue for me:

> wouldn't normally necro a thread but i spent two weeks trawling the
> internet trying to sort this out and this thread is pretty high up on
> the search rankings, hopefully can help someone.
>
> My symptoms:
>
> - Previously working bluetooth speaker (UE BOOM 2 in my case) stops connecting
> - Windows 10 'Bluetooth and other devices' menu shows the device as Paired
> - Pressing connect makes it attempt to connect but fails then it goes back to Paired
> - Remove device hides the device from the menu, but as soon as you turn bluetooth on and off, or restart the computer, the device comes
>   back
> - You pull your hair out.
>
> Solution that worked for me after much, much unsuccessful internet
> trawling and one system restore:
>
> - Download this 7 year old command line bluetooth toolset: [Bluetooth command line tools](https://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools) - work with bluetooth from the command line
> - Install it, make sure you enable the option to "Add Bluetooth Command Line Tools directory to path"
> - Open Powershell
> - Put your device that isn't working properly into pairing mode WARNING: THE FOLLOWING COMMAND WILL UNPAIR ALL BLUETOOTH DEVICES
> - type in "btpair -u"
> - Boom, all of a sudden Windows asks me if I want to allow pairing to my device that isn't working
> - Hit yes, successfully connected again
> - Cry tears of joy
>
> God I hope that helps someone else.

Comment: thanks a lot! I will try it when I'll have a time

Answer (score 1):

This **PowerShell** may help. It will display found devices and allow you to remove them via an API functionn. Copy & paste the entire code block into a **PowerShell** window:

```
$Source = @"
   [DllImport("BluetoothAPIs.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
   static extern UInt32 BluetoothRemoveDevice(IntPtr pAddress);

   public static UInt32 Unpair(UInt64 BTAddress) {
      GCHandle pinnedAddr = GCHandle.Alloc(BTAddress, GCHandleType.Pinned);
      IntPtr pAddress     = pinnedAddr.AddrOfPinnedObject();
      UInt32 result       = BluetoothRemoveDevice(pAddress);
      pinnedAddr.Free();
      return result;
   }
"@

Function Get-BTDevice {
    Get-PnpDevice -class Bluetooth |
      ?{$_.HardwareID -match 'DEV_'} |
         select Status, Class, FriendlyName, HardwareID,
            # Extract device address from HardwareID
            @{N='Address';E={[uInt64]('0x{0}' -f $_.HardwareID[0].Substring(12))}}
}

################## Execution Begins Here ################

$BTR       = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Source -Name "BTRemover"  -Namespace "BStuff" -PassThru
$BTDevices = @(Get-BTDevice) # Force array if null or single item

Do {
   If ($BTDevices.Count) {
      "`n******** Bluetooth Devices ********`n" | Write-Host
      For ($i=0; $i -lt $BTDevices.Count; $i++) {
         ('{0,5} - {1}' -f ($i+1), $BTDevices[$i].FriendlyName) | Write-Host
      }
      $selected = Read-Host "`nSelect a device to remove (0 to Exit)"
      If ([int]$selected -in 1..$BTDevices.Count) {
         'Removing device: {0}' -f $BTDevices[$Selected-1].FriendlyName | Write-Host
         $Result = $BTR::Unpair($BTDevices[$Selected-1].Address)
         If (!$Result) {"Device removed successfully." | Write-Host}
         Else {"Sorry, an error occured." | Write-Host}
      }
   }
   Else {
      "`n********* No devices found ********" | Write-Host
   }
} While (($BTDevices = @(Get-BTDevice)) -and [int]$selected)
```

Comment: wow! thanks a lot! I will try it when I'll have a time

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to unpair the headphones. You cannot do this using Device Manager. Instead, you must go to the modern control panel, the same place you go to pair new Bluetooth devices.

[image: Bluetooth & other devices]

Here, you can select the device you want to remove and just click the "Remove device" button. The device can then be paired again.

Comment: I've done this first place. The same result : If I unplug + plug my dongle again - this paired device (JBL TUNE700) appears again.
(updated main question)

Comment: According to the product information your Erston Bluetooth adapter stores pairings on the adapter. It could be malfunctioning and not deleting the pairing when instructed to do so.

Comment: could you please provide the source of this info? I couldn't find that.

Comment: That's what I get from the second image [on the product page](https://erston.com.ua/products/adapter-samzhe-bluetooth-50).