# Removed bluetooth device keeps re-appearing

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, connection

A few weeks ago I started encountering a weird issue. After attempting to re-connect my bluetooth headsets to my laptop, no connection would be established. No worries, I thought, just remove the bluetooth connection and reconnect. So I hard-reset my bluetooth headset and removed the device from my laptop's "Bluetooth & Other Devices".

This time, however, my laptop would not find my bluetooth headset again. I thought perhaps the headset was broken, but no, I could connect it perfectly well to my phone or a different computer via Bluetooth. It's only my laptop which does not seem to find the headset. To make things even weirder, the headset kept re-appearing in the list under "Other Devices", only offering the option to remove it once more without offering the option of re-connecting.

To make things stranger still, once I delete the headphones' driver in the device manager, the driver keeps re-appearing whenever I "Scan for hardware changes", and so does the listing under "Other Devices" in the Bluetooth menu.

**My layman's diagnosis**: something messed up in the communication between my headphones and my laptop, and I cannot reset and re-establish a new bluetooth connection because my laptop somehow "remembers" the headphones, even though it shouldn't, as if my deletion/removal were incomplete. Do you have any recommendations on how I can wipe the headphones from the laptop's memory for good, so that I can hopefully connect the two devices fresh again some day?

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/q/1694412/219095) is basically the same. No real solution though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googling some more, I have [found the answer in a different forum post](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/22049-how-completely-remove-bluetooth-device-win-10-a.html), which I will reproduce here for the sake of any other user encountering the same issue:

> wouldn't normally necro a thread but i spent two weeks trawling the
> internet trying to sort this out and this thread is pretty high up on
> the search rankings, hopefully can help someone.
>
> My symptoms:
>
> - Previously working bluetooth speaker (UE BOOM 2 in my case) stops connecting
> - Windows 10 'Bluetooth and other devices' menu shows the device as Paired
> - Pressing connect makes it attempt to connect but fails then it goes back to Paired
> - Remove device hides the device from the menu, but as soon as you turn bluetooth on and off, or restart the computer, the device comes
>   back
> - You pull your hair out.
>
> Solution that worked for me after much, much unsuccessful internet
> trawling and one system restore:
>
> - Download this 7 year old command line bluetooth toolset: [Bluetooth command line tools](https://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools) - work with bluetooth from the command line
> - Install it, make sure you enable the option to "Add Bluetooth Command Line Tools directory to path"
> - Open Powershell
> - Put your device that isn't working properly into pairing mode WARNING: THE FOLLOWING COMMAND WILL UNPAIR ALL BLUETOOTH DEVICES
> - type in "btpair -u"
> - Boom, all of a sudden Windows asks me if I want to allow pairing to my device that isn't working
> - Hit yes, successfully connected again
> - Cry tears of joy
>
> God I hope that helps someone else.

This worked perfectly for me!

Comment: this worked for me while having issues with my PX7 head phone. It would also automatically pair when searching for Bluetooth devices, which will prevent it from actually connecting. using btpair is was able to get it resolved.

Comment: thanks a ton, this finally worked for me after exploring so many more options.